# Looking for advice on organizing an app which is basically just a collection of functions a user can trigger

Tags: mobile, navigation, mobile-application, information-architecture

I'm currently in the process of redesigning a mobile app, which pretty much acts as a launchpad for a variety of different payment functions.

The app's current architecture relies on a bottom-navigation which consists of a home tab, two tabs which contain functions and a "more" tab which houses infrequently used functions in addition to settings and some other less used stuff.

The following is an abstraction of the architecture as it stands today:

**Tab 1:** Home

- Functions A [Priority 1]
- Functions B [Priority 1]

**Tab 2:** Category C

- Functions C [Priority 2]

**Tab 3:** Category D

- Functions D [Priority 2]

**Tab 4:** More

- Functions E [Priority 3]
- Functions F [Priority 3]
- Profile [Priority 3]
- Settings [Priority 3]

The functions within **Tab 2** & **Tab 3** I'm not concerned with, since they are tucked away in their own tab in the bottom-navigation, which allows for the easy addition of similar functions – they just slot into place in their respective tab.

**Tab 4** also doesn't pose any problems, since it's the UX equivalent of a storage cabinet (oversimplification, but you know what I mean) and fairly flexible.

**Tab 1** (Home) however is where I'm struggling. It is plastered with functions A & B which are both classified as [Priority 1] (as well as mandatory promotional content :/ ) and therefore should be made directly accessible to the users upon opening the app. The problem with that is, that this treatment of the [Priority 1] features will inevitably condemn the Home tab to an unruly soup of buttons and functions, once more things are added in the future. I want to get ahead of this...

Functions A are very important for the Business and will not budge from the first tab. I've been told to bump down Functions B to the second spot in the bottom-nav, giving them their own category. Problem with that is, that these are the functions that we know to be most popular amongst users who are pretty happy with how easily accessible they are in the current version of the app.

This leaves me in a situation where I know it's bad news in the long run to have all the functions combined on the home tab, yet I can't really separate them without displacing our users most used functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hye Joel, seems like you have an interesting case here. Would be more helpful to provide a sketch for Tab 1. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi! Here you go -> https://excalidraw.com/#room=e1916d600d33af9ef893,LB6PzWBuWlCtHiBYkx7rqg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hye again Joel, I believe what you have here is close to a 'super app' design and I am a frequent user of one. It is common in super app home screen design to be sectioned into what you already have in your sketch.

**Home Screen**
Top section: Ads/ Banner
Mid section: Top priority actions. However, some apps do cramped a lot of shortcut buttons here, and at times, this section is horizontally scrollable.
Bottom section: Least priority from the above. Usually announcements, articles.

**Reference**
You can refer this article for screenshots of a well-known super app in Asia. The article also breaks down the Information Architecture so you can see the user journey of the super app: https://uxdesign.cc/unified-payment-system-for-a-super-app-5937cca31978

A screenshot from the link above: [image]

Comment: I never heard the term "super app". Maybe because these types of apps aren't very common yet where I'm from. This will help me a lot with researching the topic! The article looks really interesting too. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes, it's common in Asia. You're very welcome Joel :)